# Не видит кнопки

Tags: c++, c++builder

Есть класс:

```
_fastcall Pult::Pult(TWinControl *Owner, TV *nv) : TPanel(Owner)
{
    Parent = Owner;
    v = nv;
    Left = v->Left + v->Width + 20;
    top_pos = 15;
    left_pos = 15;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            b[i] = new TButton(this);
            b[i]->Parent = this;
            b[i]->Height = 30;
            b[i]->Caption = IntToStr(i+1);
            b[i]->OnClick = OnPultClick;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            if(i < 3)
                    b[i]->Top = 0;
            else if(i >= 3 && i < 6)
                    b[i]->Top = b[0]->Height;
            else if(i >= 6 && i < 9)
                    b[i]->Top = b[0]->Height * 2;
            else
                    b[i]->Top = b[0]->Height * 3;
            b[i]->Top += top_pos;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            b[i]->Left = left_pos;
            left_pos += b[i]->Width;
            if(i + 1 == 3 || i + 1 == 6)
                    left_pos = 15;
            else if(i + 1 == 10)
                    b[i]->Left = b[0]->Left + b[0]->Width;
    }

    Width = b[0]->Width * 3 + 30;
    Height = b[0]->Height * 4 + 30;
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку нужно вывести Caption кнопки. Вот как я это делаю:

```
void __fastcall Pult::OnPultClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    v->setChannel(StrToInt((TButton*(Sender))->Caption)));
}
```

Но при запуске программы, появляется ошибка `Improper use of typedef 'TButton'`, и указывает на мой обработчик.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Так наверное не `при запуске программы`, а при компиляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно расставил скобки в обработчике. Вот так правильно:

```
v->setChannel(StrToInt(((TButton*)Sender)->Caption));
```